# Having problems structuring Cheerio scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I think this may be just basic syntax.  I'm coming from Java and very new to Javascript.  For example, when I see a $ in all the examples, my mind goes blank.

Code for parsing the HTTP request (which contains a bunch of dog shows) looks like (using the request library):

```
function parseRequest1(error, response, body) {
    // TODO  should check for error...
    var Cheerio = require('cheerio');
    parser = Cheerio.load(body);

    var table2 = parser('.qs_table[bgcolor="#71828A"]');
    var showList = [];

    // skip over a bunch of crap to find the table.  Each row with this BG color represents a dog show
    var trows = parser('tr[bgcolor="#FFFFFF"]', table2);
    trows.each(function(i, tablerow) {
        var show = parseShow(tablerow);
        if (show)  // returns a null if something went wrong
            showList.push(show);
    });

    // then do something with showList...

}
```

which is called by

```
Request.get(URL, parseRequest1);
```

So far, so good.  Where I'm stuck is in how to write the parseShow function.  I'd like to go something like

```
function parseShow(tableRow) {
    var tds = parser('td', tableRow);
    //and then go through the tds scraping info...
}
```

but I get an error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'find'
    at new module.exports (C:\Users\Morgan\WebstormProjects\agility\node_modules\cheerio\lib\cheerio.js:76:18)
    at exports.load.initialize (C:\Users\Morgan\WebstormProjects\agility\node_modules\cheerio\lib\static.js:19:12)
    at parseShow (C:\Users\Morgan\WebstormProjects\agility\routes\akc.js:20:15)
```

Looking at the stack trace, it looks like Cheerio is creating a new one.  How am I supposed to pass the Cheerio parser down to the second function?  Right now parser is a global var in the file.

I've tried a bunch of random things like these but they don't work either:

```
var tds = tableRow('td');
var tds = Cheerio('td', tableRow);
```

What I'm forced to do instead is a bunch of disgusting, fragile code accessing `tableRow.children[1], tableRow.children[3]`, etc...  (the HTML has /r/ns all over creation so many of the children are whitespace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know what you mean about the `$(..)`. The $ is just a function name. I think it was chosen as it's short and catches the eye.

Used with Cheerio, and more generally JQuery, it is used with css selectors:

```
var table2 = $('.qs_table[bgcolor="#71828A"]');
```

The advantage of this is that table2 is now a `selector Object` and will have a `.find()` method which can be called.

In Jquery (I'm not so sure about Cheerio), the `selector Object` is also a collection, so multiple elements can be matched (or none).

The object model in javascript is a lot more dynamic than Java which can lead to much shorter - if more confusing code.

The code to parse table rows:

```
 $('tr[bgcolor="#FFFFFF"]').each(function(i, tablerow) {
    var show = tablerow.text();
    if (show)  // returns a null if something went wrong
        showList.push(show);
 });
```

In your code above `parser(..)` is used rather than `$(..)`. However once, the object has been loaded with the body you can just keep using it:

```
parser('tr[bgcolor="#FFFFFF"]').each(function(i, tablerow) {
```

or to just find the rows of the table you want the following:

```
parser('.qs_table[bgcolor="#71828A"] tr[bgcolor="#FFFFFF"]').each(function(i, tablerow) {
```

The selector is css so this will find all `tr[bgcolor="#FFFFFF"]` elements which are children of the `.qs_table[bg="#71828A']` element.

Comment: Thanks for some tips!  It looks like, for the second, nested find of tds, I have to go `var tds = parser(tableRow).children('td')` instead of `var tds = parser('td', tableRow);`  Cause it's returning multiple items???

Comment: I don't think you can (or need to) pass the tableRow object in like that, something more like `var tds = parser('.qs_table[bgcolor="#71828A"] tr[bgcolor="#FFFFFF"] td')`

Comment: I was trying to save time by not repeating the possibly long selection path every time.  e.g., once I had found the qs_table, use it as the start for any future searches for trs, then use the trs as the start for tds, etc...  Not sure if that is needed or not.  Anyway, at least in Cheerio, `parser(someNodeObject).doSomethingFromThere()` seems to work in the manner I am thinking.

Comment: I have seen tutorials for Beautiful soup structured like that. However, you need only use one big selector instead of multiple steps, which will be faster still.